# VMware Workstation - Use a Dedicated NIC on a desktop with two NICs

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware, workstation

I have installed a used Intel Pro/1000PT Quad in my workstation so VM's can have a dedicated NIC.  Is there any HOWTO's on how to make sure the host does NOT use the port and to correctly configure the Virtual Network Editor?  At the moment there are three networks: VMnet0 (bridged), VMnet1 (Host-only), VMnet8 (NAT).  I tried:

1. changing VMnet0 (Bridged) to use the Intel Pro/1000PT Ethernet 4
2. Assign VMnet0 to the VM
3. starts up VM machine and no network

When going into Network Connections, Intel Pro/1000PT Ethernet 4 does have an IP on the network.

What am I doing wrong, how do I configure this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

VMware Workstation has a Network Editor in the VMware folder.

User the Network editor to establish which Network Adapter is to be used for Bridged Networking.

Set up your VM (VM Settings) to use the Bridged Network as you have established it for a specific card.

There is only one Bridge Network setting for all the virtual machines that might use it. That will be for the card you set up.  Other machines can also use NAT.

[image]

Comment: Warning to others:  Pay close attention to the name of the actual NIC.  In Windows Control Panel > Network Connection the port I am using is labeled "Ethernet 4" but when I look at it properties it say "Intel(R) PRO/1000 PT Quad Port LP Server Adapter #3", I had been selecting Intel(R) PRO/1000 PT Quad Port LP Server Adapter #4 and it was not working... Now that I setting the Bridge to: #3, it works!